# Jquery dialog for multplie dynamic links in coldfusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am creating an event calendar in coldfusion, jquery. I have the below code. If i have only one event that ie one link per day, and on click the dialog box opens up. When i have more than one event/hyperlinks for a day, it does not open the dialog box to show event details, instead the page is reloading when I click the second link....can someone pls point as to what is wrong with this code?

```
 <table id="calendar" align="center">
      <tr>
         <td class="cal-nav">
         <font color="##FFFFFF">   <a href="#cp#?date=#lastMonth#"><- Previous</a></font>
        </td>
         <td class="cal-hdr" colspan="5">
         <font color="##FFFFFF">   #DateFormat(thisMonth, "mmmm - yyyy")#</font>
        </td>
         <td class="cal-nav">
        <font color="##FFFFFF">    <a href="#cp#?date=#nextMonth#">Next -></a></font>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr align="center">
        <cfloop from="1" to="7" index="i">
        <td class="cal-day"><font color="##FFFFFF">#DateFormat(i, "DDDD")#</font></td>
        </cfloop>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
         <cfloop from="1" to="42" index="j">
            <cfif (j LTE 7) AND (DateFormat(thisMonth, "DDDD") IS DateFormat(j, "DDDD"))>
               <cfset showDays = true />
            </cfif>
            <cfif thisDay GT totalDays>
               <cfset showDays = false />
            </cfif>


            <cfif showDays>
               <cfset squareDate = "#DateFormat(thisMonth, "MM")#/#thisDay#/#DateFormat(thisMonth, "YYYY")#" />

               <td class="cal-square cal-day-active top <cfif squareDate EQ DateFormat(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")>cal-today</cfif>">
                  <table>
                     <tr>                    
                        <cfset duedate = DateFormat(getdetails.duedate, "MM/D/YYYY")>


                        <td>
                          <div>#thisDay#</div>                           
                         <cfloop query="getdetails">                                                   
                         <cfif #duedate# eq #squareDate#>
                           <div id="view-#thisDay#-#getdetails.motsid#" class="cal-event" style="margin-top:5px" > 

                           <a id="event" href="">
                   <cfif squareDate LT DateFormat(Now(), "MM/D/YYYY")><font color="red" ><strong>#getdetails.PROGRAM#</strong> <cfelse> #getdetails.PROGRAM#</font></cfif>
                           </a>                           
                           </div>
                          </cfif>                        
                          </cfloop> 

                          <cfloop query="getdetails">                                                   
                         <cfif #duedate# eq #squareDate#>
                           <div id="dialog-#thisDay#" class="window" title="#getdetails.PROGRAM#">                             
                              <div class="event-date">#DateFormat(duedate,"DDDD - MMMM DD, YYYY")#</div>
                              <div><p>MOTSID:#getdetails.motsid#</p></div>
                           </div>            
                         </cfif>                        
                          </cfloop> 





<script type="text/javascript">
                       $(function() {
                          $(".test-#thisDay#-#getdetails.motsid#").click(function(a) {                              
                             a.preventDefault();    
                             $('##dialog-#thisDay#').dialog('open');                                                        

                          });
                       });
              </script>




                        </td>


                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
               <cfset thisDay = thisDay + 1 />
            <cfelse>
               <td class="cal-square cal-day-null"></td>
            </cfif> 
            <cfif j MOD 7 IS 0></tr>
               <cfif NOT j NEQ 42><tr></cfif>
            </cfif>
         </cfloop>
      </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: this... <cfif #duedate# eq #squareDate#>  should be <cfif duedate eq squareDate>  (no "#" signs).  You only need to put those in when something is quoted or being output.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, btu why are you looping over a query and then adding a `script` tag for each item....with an `onload` handler and selector for each individual link. You should simply give each link a class and have one selector that uses this class.

Comment: I fixed it.... needed to pass a unique id into the jquery function, updated the code...thanks for your replies

Comment: You did not 'fix' the code. The loop where you create a `script` tag for each iteration is just wrong - it may work, but it is the wrong way to approach this problem. take a look at the source code on that page and you will see what I mean.

Comment: yes i see your point....though it is working, the script is being looped...when i remove the cfloop onclick is jsut reloading the page...

Comment: I have updated the code above, the dialog box doesnot open, and the page only reloads on click.